# Customize the delete button in UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, customization

I have the functionality for "Swipe to delete" the `TableViewCell`. I want to customize the **Delete** button. [image]

Is this possible, and how to access the **Delete** button ?

Comment: try these http://stackoverflow.com/q/8603431/194544 http://stackoverflow.com/q/1615469/194544

Comment: @beryllium so your advice would be to create a custom cell? But I have already build the cell, I'd rather set a gesture recognizer then make this one as a custom cell.

Comment: You want action for the delete button or you need to change the delete button

Comment: Just have a look at my answer but make sure you need to have a customcell @Spire

Comment: @Spire, How did you customize delete button. Share your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This method will be called when user performs the swipe action**

**Just Place this in your CustomCell**

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
    {
        [super willTransitionToState:state];
        if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)
        {
            for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
            {
                if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"])
                {
                    UIImageView *deleteBtn = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 33)];
                    [deleteBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_left_s11.png"]];
                    [[subview.subviews objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:deleteBtn];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**You should not try that, you are not supposed to alter Apple's default views .**

Comment: I have found another way to delete, but thanks for your effort. I will get mor educated on this as I will need it for another projects. thx **One thing, I dont use custom cell, that's why I needed info on how to change the DELETE appearance, to look like the Nudge button**

Comment: You should not try that, you are not supposed to alter Apple's default views . Did you see this ?

Comment: Not true, You can do all kinds of custom UI hacks and if they add to the product Apple will accept them. We do custom UI all the time.

Answer (score 13):

If you only need to change the title of the button, you only need to add the titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return @"NewButtonName";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
   {
    //   Your Code
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, and how to call the Delete button here in `// Your Code` section? How can I change it in `UIButtonTypeCustom`?

Comment: This is inBuilt functionality of Table , so you can do whatever you want , like removing value from array   for  e.g.-    [idArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
where idArray is NSMutableArray having ids .   In the end just reload your Table by calling [tableView reloaddata]; where tableView is your table's name.