# Customizing the default delete button and icon in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

I am trying to change the default button to delete a row in a tableview (when the user swipe left).
[Changing the height of the default confirmation delete button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiYgH.png)

At the same time i would like to add a custom image on the left side of the cell when entering the edit mode...
[Changing the default icon when entering the edit mode to delete[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjSiu.png)

I've included in my code the:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "\u{267A}\n Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        tableView.isEditing = false
        print("delete")
        // delete item at indexPath
    }

    return [delete]
}
```

is it possible to change the heigh of the confirmation delete button and add a custom image for the left icon?

Thanks! 
:)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can once check the site again. the question has already been asked and answered previously

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35648526/1457385

Comment: i've seen the answer... and definitely i'm doing smt wrong.... i did insert the image... but the height of the button is still the same of the row... what i'm trying to do is to change the height of the button and make it different from the height of the row...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set UIImage to backgroundColor of UITableViewRowAction.

```
let someAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "") { value in 
        println("button did tapped!")
    }
    someAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "myImage")!)
```

Comment: What about the image size? It's should be smaller, right?

Comment: Why write extra code when you can resize the image as per your requirement??

Comment: What did you mean? Your answer is excellent and I want to know how it's done.

Comment: the image is smaller... but here's what it does....https://prnt.sc/fr15sq I'm new to swift... and i'm afraid i'm missing something in your explanation... sorry...

Comment: the reason your image is getting populated so many times is because it is very small. If you just pick up an larger image depending upon your size of the cell, It wouldn't do so.

Comment: i know... but that was my question... :) sorry maybe i didn't express myself correctly... what i would like to do... is to have a the button with a different dimension compared to the cell... i would like to have the button smaller compared to the cell.... is it possibile to change just the height of the button?

Comment: @Marco what we are doing is, we are giving only the back ground to the row action. In the background instead of a color, we are giving the image. Since the background covers the entire area of the row action, you need to select a bigger image. Try for a new pic and if the colors are different, just edit them in paint.