# UITableView edit mode - customize color of minus sign delete button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is there a way to customize the color of the minus sign delete button when a UITableView is in edit mode? Designer needs it to be a deeper red to be consistent with our app's color scheme. Please note that I am talking about the circle minus sign delete icon on the left, not the delete confirmation buttons on the right:

[image]

SO posts I have found such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290766/change-the-color-of-default-red-color-delete-button-in-uitableviewcell-when-swip) are all about customizing the delete confirmation buttons on the right hand side.

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18648021/775896

Comment: Thank you @Mrunal , that one is also about the swipe to left delete button - "UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl" refers to the confirmation button that shows up after tapping the little cross

Comment: I am trying to find this also!

Answer (score 0):

this function works for me, just put it before return the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath table view delegate method:

```
+(void) setImageToDeleteBtnInCell:(UITableViewCell*) cell image:(UIImage*) image{
for (UIView *subv in cell.subviews){
    if ([NSStringFromClass([subv class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]) {
        int i = 0;
        for (UIView *imgV in subv.subviews){
            if (i == 1){
                if([imgV isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){

                    ((UIImageView*) imgV).image = image;
                    //imgV.tintColor = [ObjcThemeConnector getMainColor];
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: What about the size of the image view? If I pass an image that doesn't have the exact expected size, the frame takes the size of the image and it's not possible to resize it, for some reason.