# Prevent UITableViewCell shift to left and delete button appears while editing table

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I wonder if there is a way how to prevent UITableViewCell shift to left and delete button appears while editing table. I want custom popup appears on pressing red circle. Does anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible Duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/a/15564663/1597744

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603431/create-custom-delete-button-for-uitableview

Comment: that doesn't work on iOS7

Comment: One way to prevent moving the cell's content is to turn off autolayout in your cell's xib.

Comment: it's off but still same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Replace subviews loop in will/didTransitionToState to look like this(if you want to support older iOS versions too, use answers in linked questions). This will find delete button on iOS 7.

```
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        for (UIView *subview2 in subview.subviews) {
            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview2 class]) rangeOfString:@"Delete"].location != NSNotFound) {
                // Do whatever you want here
            }
        }
    }
```